# Stop IE8 message "web page stopped responding" while debugging

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, internet-explorer-8

IE8 has a feature that pops up a dialog box that informs me when a web page stops responding that's a bit annoying when debugging as it steals focus from visual studio.  Is there a way to disable that feature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was just covered on the IEBlog [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/ie/archive/2009/05/04/ie8-in-windows-7-rc-reliability-and-telemetry.aspx).

From the blog:

> While we continue to track the
>   telemetry, if you are debugging IE
>   either with the IE Developer Tools or
>   a debugger, and you attempt to
>   interact with the IE window, there is
>   a chance that you will see this
>   dialog. Although this will not impact
>   your debugging it may be more
>   convenient to turn this dialog off. Or
>   if you’re running Win7 RC and are
>   seeing this prompt more than you
>   should or would want to, you can turn
>   it off by changing the following
>   registry key:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main!HangResistance, DWORD, 0
```